# Progress bar in Android Web View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I did an Android app using Xamarin.Native. It works fine but it have a problem. When I click in any link, it doesn't show anything in the screen to show it is loading the next page. Any ideas?

```
  namespace name
    {
       [Activity(Label = "name", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {
            WebView web_view;
            int count = 1;

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

                web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
                web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                web_view.LoadUrl("http://mimabebes.es");
                web_view.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            }

            public override bool OnKeyDown(Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (keyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.Back && web_view.CanGoBack())
                {
                    web_view.GoBack();
                    return true;
                }

                return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to show some code. What you have try.

Comment: thats what I have

Answer (score 0):

There are two override methods:

- `OnPageStarted`
- `OnPageFinished`

You can write the code to show the progress bar in `OnPageStarted` and hide the progress in `OnPageFinished` method.

```
public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
{
    base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    // Code to show the progress bar
}

public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
{
    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    // Code to hide the progress bar
}
```